# Do you need copies of protobufs in both client and server in web applications?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to post this question, but I'm trying to learn gRPC/protobufs in the context of a web application. I am building the UI in Flutter, and the backend in Go with MongoDB. I was able to get a simple go service running and I was able to query it using Kreya, however my question now is - how do I integrate the UI with the backend? In order to make the Kreya call, I needed to import the protobufs. Do I need to maintain identical protobufs in both the front end and backend? Meaning, do I literally have to copy all of my protobufs in the backend into my UI codebase and compile locally there as well? This seems like a nightmare to maintain, as now the protobufs have to be maintained in two places, as opposed to one.

What is the best way to maintain the protobufs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but think of the protos as a shared (contract) between your clients and servers.

The protos define the interface by which the client is able to communicate with the server. In order for this to be effective, the client and server need to implement the same interface.

One way to do this is to store your protos in a repo that you share in any clients and servers that implement it. This provides a single source of truth of the protos. I also generate copies of the protos compiled (`protoc`) to the languages I will use e.g. Golang, Dart etc. in this shared protos repo and import from the repo where needed.

Then, in your case, the client imports the Dart-generated sources and the Golang server imports the Golang-generated sources from the shared repo.

Alternatively, your client and your server could `protoc` compile appropriate sources when they need them, on-the-fly, usually as part of an automated build process.

Try not to duplicate the protos across clients and servers because it will make it challenging to maintain consistency; it will be challenging to ensure every copy remains synchronized.

Comment: Hmm, ok, that makes sense, but could you clarify what you mean by `store your protos in a repo that you share`? I'm using a single repo for my UI and backend codebase, but while the server may be able to access the protos anywhere, that wouldn't be the case with my UI codebase - how can I share them between the two?

Comment: If you're using a single repo, then you need not create another. In your repo, let's assume you have client, server and a directory containing the protos. Then, you will use `protoc` to generate the Golang sources for the server and the Dart sources for the client. You'll import the Golang sources into the server and these will form part of its binary. You'll import the Dart sources (`something.pb.dart` and `something.pbgrpc.dart`) into your client and these will form part of its binary that your clients install.

Comment: So let's take that example. We have 3 directories in the root directory, `client`, `server`, `protos`. Are you saying that the protobufs are compiled into both the client and server? Meaning the `*.pb.go` files are in the `server/protos` and `*.pb.dart` are in the `client/lib/protos`? Or are you saying that `proto`, contains `*.proto`, `*.pb.go` and `*.pb.dart`? If the former, I think that makes sense. If the latter, isn't a web application bound to its source directory? It wouldn't be able to access `protos/*.pb.dart` from outside of `client/lib` (since I'm working in Flutter)

Comment: Also, in the case of the former, I currently have a `option go_package = <some_path>;` in my code, how would that work with a single source of protobufs for two different languages (go and dart/flutter)?

Comment: To follow the model in which the `protos` is its own (GitHub) repo, when you use a shared `/protos` directory, the generated protos stay within the `/protos` subdirectory and you treat this as a module|package|namespace depending on your preferred language. In the case of Golang, you can use `go_package` and `--go[-grpc]_opt=module=${MODULE}` to reflect the location and I assume there's a solution for Dart too. Good luck!